# Why are there two options to "Change T2 Unlimited" in AWS Console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In the online AWS Console, right-click a T2 or T3 instance, hover over Instance Settings, and you'll see several options. Two of these options are "Change T2 Unlimited" and "Change T2/T3 Unlimited".

[image: Screenshot of AWS Console Instance Settings menu]

**Why are there two options that apparently do the same thing?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it is because Unlimited has changed slightly between T2 and T3.

From [Unlimited Mode - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-unlimited.html):

- T3 instances are launched as *unlimited* by default.
- T2 instances are launched as *standard* by default.

There are also differences in the way startup credits are issued:

- T3 *Standard* and T3 *Unlimited* instances never receive launch credits.

I haven't tested it, but I suspect the reason for the two menu options is the ability to set T3 settings separate to T2 settings, in case the instance type is changed between the two, for purposes of **backwards-compatibility**.